# Custom Validation Classes in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, class, validation

I am trying to make a custom validation class in ruby on rails, however I cannot figure out how to make it modular.

I followed this example:
[Validator Class Example](http://backstage.official.fm/ruby/build-your-own-rails-custom-validators/)

For the second example on that page titled: "Validate object single states with an isolated custom validator" how can I put the PreventFutureDateValidator class into a separate file? I cannot figure out where these files would be placed in Ruby on Rails.

Answer (score 0):

These kindo of files are normally stored in `/lib`.

Answer (score 0):

It's common to put validator classes in `/app/validators/`